# Which HTTP code to reject cross-domain access

Tags: http-headers, cross-domain

I've been looking for but didn't find a definitive answer to the following question :

Which would be the correct HTTP status code to send to reject a cross-domain connection attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the 403 Forbidden, with a correct error message. Because as the RFC says:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use status code 418 . Each to there own though